# How is Cross Validated represented on Twitter?

Tags: discussion

I wanted to promote a question to my Twitter followers, and I thought I might find a Twitter stream of CV questions that would have something I could retweet. I only found [@statsqa](https://twitter.com/statsqa) which tweets some messages, but not the one I was looking for ([How to Distinguish 22 Variables in a Stacked Bar Graph?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/243697/how-to-distinguish-22-variables-in-a-stacked-bar-graph)).

What is the function of @statsqa Twitter account? Is/should there be a stream of all questions? Or maybe those with some vote threshold?

If some rule already exists, it would good to explain it in the Twitter account's bio.

Comment: I think this is relevant http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183407/how-does-the-twitter-bot-work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To expand on [Glen_b's comment](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4425/how-is-cross-validated-represented-on-twitter?cb=1#comment11252_4425):

> I think this is relevant [meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183407/...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183407/how-does-the-twitter-bot-work)

---

The official Twitter account for this stack is [@StackStats](https://twitter.com/StackStats).

You can see this if you go to [this page](http://stackexchange.com/sites#science-oldest) and click on the Twitter link below our site name.